# Azure Application Insights explorer

Tags: azure, analytics, azure-application-insights, mobile-analytics

This is not a programming question.

Is there a tool out there that lets me explore my exported App Insights data and do advanced things like funnels and graphing different metrics? I'm thinking something like Mixpanel or other anayltics websites but that would work on my own data from Application Insights.

Azure Portal is too limited e.g. it doesn't have funnels and it's too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Try Power BI with Application Insights content pack. [Here is a short guide how to get started](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-content-pack-application-insights/)

Comment: oh, great! I've never heard of that before. I'll try that out, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should create a continuous export of your app insights data.
Just create or use an storage account, and then in azure portal goto Application Insights settings and configure the continuous export feature

[image: Continuous export]

#### Full article: [Export telemetry from Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-insights-export-telemetry/)

Once you have your data, you can process it in any way with the tool you want.

Comment: I know how to export the data. I'm asking if there are tools that already know how to handle Azure data and provide me with advanced features like funnels.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I miss understand the question.